# mysqlで登録数を求めるsql

Tags: mysql, sql

以下の2つのようなテーブル(table1、table2)があるときに、
table2に対してtable1のid毎の登録数でソートした結果(table3)を出したいのですが、SQLだけで可能でしょうか？

table1

id　　　|  name
‐‐‐‐‐+‐‐‐‐‐‐‐
I0001　| 12345
I0002　| abcde
I0003　| 67890
I0004　| fghij
I0005　| あああ

table2
id　　　　|　name　　|　table1_id
‐‐‐‐‐‐+‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐+‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐
B0001　|　aaaaaa　|　I0002 / I0004
B0002　|　bbbbbb　|　I0005
B0003　|　cccccc　|
B0004　|　dddddd　|　I0001 / I0004 / I0005
B0005　|　eeeeee　|　I0004

求める結果
table3
id　　 |　name　　|　cnt
‐‐‐‐+‐‐‐‐‐‐‐+‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐
I0004 |　fghij　　 |   3
I0005 |　あああ　|   2
I0001 |　12345　|   1
I0002 |　abcde　|   1
I0003 |　67890　|   0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table1_id`のところは正規化されずに / 区切りにされているのでしょうか？
`LIKE`で部分一致をしていますがその部分はカラム仕様に合わせてください。

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table1_id LIKE CONCAT(N'%', table1.id, N'%')) AS cnt
FROM table1
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
思い通りの結果が出できました。

Answer (score 0):

下記のような感じでどうでしょうか？

```
select tbl1.id,tbl1.name,id_cnt.cnt 
from `table1` as tbl1, (
    select count(*) as cnt 
    from `table1` as tbl1, `table2` as tbl2 
    where tbl2.table1_id LIKE '%'+tbl1.id+'%'
) as id_cnt;
```

ID……というより情報が区切り文字で管理されているのは、
データベースとして、ちょっと管理しづらいかと思いますので正規化を検討してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 貴重なご意見ありがとうございます。
他の部分にも影響がありますので、影響がないようでしたら正規化の検討をします。